# how to halt function in actionscript after enter frame

Tags: actionscript-3, air, block

in my air procedure,I write a function like this:

```
public function getDataFromXml():void
{
    for each()
    {.....} //here may contain thounds of fields and name
}
```

of course,the function may cost 10s-20s,so I want add a progressbar,then the problem appears,the progressbar just be blocked.I find one frame cost about 40ms,so  the reason must be the executing the program in the interval of frames,how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to monitor the time spent in your loop, if this time exceeds the allowed time for a frame, then wait for the next one.

```
private var _dummy:Sprite = new Sprite();
private var _data:Array;

public function getDataFromXml():void
{
    var startTime:Number = getTimer();
    const allowedTime:Number = 1000 / stage.frameRate;

    while (getTimer() - startTime < allowedTime && _data.length > 0)
    {
         _data.pop(); //pop your data to remove the treated lines, or keep track of the current index
         //do your treatment here
    }
    if (_data.length == 0)
    {
       //the end
    }
    else
    {
        //wait for the next frame to go on
        _dummy.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onNextFrame);
    }
}

private function onNextFrame(event:Event):void
{
    _dummy.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onNextFrame);
    getDataFromXml();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason of your issue is that as much Flash tries to follow it's asked frame speed, it must finish all script execution in one frame before being able to go to the next. Thus, if your foreach needs 40s to execute, then Flash won't be able to pass to the next frame until the 40s are reached.

The main solution to this problem is : You must make this execution asynchronous.
There is a couple ways to do it.

The first way is to cut your execution in smaller parts. Since you use a loop, that can be pretty easy, by limiting the number of steps you loop can take in one frame. Basically, it could look like a bit like this :

```
private var _getDataIndex:Number;
private var _extractedData:Array;

public function getDataFromXml():void
{
    _getDataIndex = 0;
    _extractedData = new Array();
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, getDataFromXmlStep); // You can also use a Timer instead
    for each()
    {.....} //here may contain thounds of fields and name
}

private function getDataFromXmlStep(evt:Event):void
{
  for(var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var field:XML = _myXMLData[_getDataIndex];
    if (field == null) {
      getDataFromXmlFinished()
      break;
    }
    {.....} // your code for the field, the result saved in _extractedData
    _getDataIndex++;
  }
}
private function getDataFromXmlFinished():void {
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, getDataFromXmlStep); // You can also use a Timer instead
    // extraction finished
}
```

Another solution if you use AIR 3.4 or above, is to use a [Worker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html). Simply put, you delegate the work to an other thread which doesn't display anything an can turn autonomously while the main code do other things (manage interaction with the windows).
Workers are a good thing to learn, but are limited in that you need a recent version of AIR for them to work.

Comment: Workers can be used in non AIR version also.
*
Note: The use of workers for concurrency is only supported in Flash Player and in AIR on desktop platforms. Concurrency is not supported on mobile AIR platforms. You can use the static isSupported property to check whether concurrency is supported before attempting to use it.*

Comment: Yup, but since Vigor's question is about AIR, I only gave the minimum version for AIR. For Flash Player, it's 11.4 or above.